# What does this Android/Java code do?

Tags: android, comments

I'm new to coding Android. I have been thrown into a project and the code below works but I don't really understand it, which isn't really going to help me learn. Would someone comment the code with what each stage is doing?

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
        TreeMap<String, ?> keys = new TreeMap<String, Object>(myPrefs.getAll());
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
            Log.i("map values", entry.getKey());

        }


      List<Pair<Object, String>> sortedByValue = new LinkedList<Pair<Object,String>>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
            Pair<Object, String> e = new Pair<Object, String>(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
            sortedByValue.add(e);
        }


     // Pair doesn't have a comparator, so you're going to need to write one.
        Collections.sort(sortedByValue, new Comparator<Pair<Object, String>>() {
            public int compare(Pair<Object, String> lhs, Pair<Object, String> rhs) {

                String sls = String.valueOf(lhs.first);
                String srs = String.valueOf(rhs.first);
                int res = sls.compareTo(srs);
                // Sort on value first, key second
                return res == 0 ? lhs.second.compareTo(rhs.second) : res;
            }
        });

        for (Pair<Object, String> pair : sortedByValue) {
            Log.i("map values", pair.first + "/" + pair.second);
        }


      Collection<?> stringArrayList = keys.values();
      final CharSequence[] prefsCharSequence = stringArrayList.toArray(new CharSequence[stringArrayList.size()]);
```

Comment: in the future, you should probably step through the code in a debugger to see what it's doing. then, if you still have questions, post on SO. you didn't actually ask a specific question

Comment: This is not what SO is for. You should not be using code if you don't understand what it does. Ask whoever it was you got it from. (And any code you pulled from the 'net should have a description of it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    TreeMap<String, ?> keys = new TreeMap<String, Object>(myPrefs.getAll());
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
        Log.i("map values", entry.getKey());

    }
```

Logging all key-value pairs in the shared preference file.

```
List<Pair<Object, String>> sortedByValue = new LinkedList<Pair<Object,String>>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
        Pair<Object, String> e = new Pair<Object, String>(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        sortedByValue.add(e);
    }
```

Converting the Map that has all of the settings into a List for sorting

```
Collections.sort(sortedByValue, new Comparator<Pair<Object, String>>() {
        public int compare(Pair<Object, String> lhs, Pair<Object, String> rhs) {

            String sls = String.valueOf(lhs.first);
            String srs = String.valueOf(rhs.first);
            int res = sls.compareTo(srs);
            // Sort on value first, key second
            return res == 0 ? lhs.second.compareTo(rhs.second) : res;
        }
    });
```

Custom comparator to sort the list of Pairs. it compares the values. if they are equal, it compares a second value.

```
for (Pair<Object, String> pair : sortedByValue) {
        Log.i("map values", pair.first + "/" + pair.second);
    }
```

Print the sorted preferences.

```
  Collection<?> stringArrayList = keys.values();
  final CharSequence[] prefsCharSequence = stringArrayList.toArray(new CharSequence[stringArrayList.size()]);
```

Convert the keys from the SharedPreferences file into a Collection, which is then converted into a list of Strings.